# Is there a function to compare a part of two PNG images rather than full using C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, bitmap, png

I am using .NET Framework on Visual Studio 2019 IDE to write an algorithm for comparing two images.

While comparison works ok if I compare the whole png but the issue is that picture which is master copy ( against which newly generated image is compared) is taken in the past with timestamp of older date and time on the top left corner due to which the latest picture generated always generates failure result that is images do not match because of the time difference in timestamps on the picture.
Currently I am using following which works ok with the same timestamped images

```
System.Drawing
System.Drawing.Imaging
Bitmap original_image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imageFile);
Bitmap test_image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(testimageFile);
if(object.Equals(original_image,test_image)
return true
BitmpaData bitmapDataMasterPicture = original_image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0,original_image.Width,original_image.Height),ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
BitmpaData bitmapDataTestPicture = test_image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0,test_image.Width,test_image.Height),ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

for(int i = 0; i<totalBytes-1 ;i++)
if(bitmapDataMasterPicture[i] != bitmapDataTestPicture[i])
{
return false;
}
original_image.UnlockBits(bitmapDataMasterPicture);
test_image.UnlockBits(bitmapDataTestPicture);
```

Is there a function/algorithm to compare a part of two png images rather than full using C# ? That is skipping the timestamp on the left top corner.

Comment: _While comparison works ok if I compare the whole png_ Hm, we don't see your code, so we can't tell you how to adapt it. It hope you are actually comapring the images and not just references??

Comment: This: `object.Equals(original_image,test_image)` is comparing two references, it will always return `false`, since the references are clearly not the same. To determine equality related to the content, you need to parse the Bitmaps data, in a way or another. Parse the data using `Bitmap.LockBits()` or simply load the images bytes and compare using `SequenceEquals()` (must be identical).

Comment: You literally give a `Rectangle` for the area to lock to the `LockBits` operation. All you need to do is adjust the coords and size of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could crop the image or draw a solid rectangle covering the timestamp.

```
Graphics oGraphics= Graphics.FromImage(original_image);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);
oGraphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), rect);
```

Comment: @jimi thanks for the response I will edit question with more detail. I am actually using Bitmap.LockBits() after the code I have already attached. But issue is how to remove a part of image that is timesstamp from both images and compare the rest of the png image.

Comment: Well, if you know how many rows to skip, then simply do that..! - There are many examples around on how to use a x-y-double loop to go over the lockbit pixels..

Comment: Hi @TaW how can I skip rows?

Comment: You would start at a suitable offset. For a x-y loop to skip 30 rows of pixel start y at 30; for a single loop start it at (width+stride) * 30 * bpp..

Comment: @A786 You should never go over all bytes when using LockBits; the length of each line on a bitmap gets rounded up to the next multiple of 4 bytes and can thus contain bytes that are not part of the actual image data. You should go over it line by line, using the `Stride` you can retrieve from the BitmapData object as data width, but only checking the actual (width * bpp) for the pixel data. (Admitted this matters less in 32bppARGB since a pixel is 4 bytes, but it's important to grasp the principle.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thank you for your responses. I managed to fix the problem by setting an offset on y-axis that is in function as shown below:

```
    BitmpaData bitmapDataMasterPicture = original_image.LockBits(new 
 Rectangle(0,10,original_image.Width,original_image.Height),ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);


BitmpaData bitmapDataTestPicture = test_image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,10,test_image.Width,test_image.Height),ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```